# IMPORT_STAR = oncode.opmap["IMPORT_STAR"]

Tags: python, compiler-errors, pyinstaller

I tried to make an executable of my python script using cx_Freeze. However it keeps returning an error (See title).

setup.py

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

import os

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tcl8.6"
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = "C:\\LOCAL_TO_PYTHON\\Python35-32\\tcl\\tk8.6"

setup(
    name="YourAppName",
    version="1.0",
    description="Your application description",
    executables=[Executable("your_script.py")],
)
```

app.py

```
import os
import shutil
import time


# Check file type
def get_folder_location(file):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        return "C:/Users/marti/OneDrive/Documenten/_pdf"
    elif file.endswith((".docx", ".doc", ".odt")):
        return "C:/Users/marti/OneDrive/Documenten/_docx"
    elif file.endswith((".xlsx", ".csv", ".xls", ".ods")):
        return "C:/Users/marti/OneDrive/Documenten/_xlsx"
    elif file.endswith((".pptx", ".ppt", ".odp")):
        return "C:/Users/marti/OneDrive/Documenten/_pptx"
    else:
        return None

# Ga door folder heen
def scan_folder(folder_path):
    start_time = time.time()
     
    # Scan items in geselecteerde map
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
         for item in files:
            print(f"item found: {item}")
            item_path = os.path.join(root, item)
            folder_location = get_folder_location(item)

            if folder_location:
                shutil.move(item_path, folder_location)
            else:
                print("Filetype niet gevonden")


    # Print run time
    end_time = time.time()
    runtime = end_time - start_time
    print(f"Runtime: {runtime}")


scan_folder(input("Folder: "))
```

Does someone know how to fix this, or is there another solution to work around the Windows Defender?

Ofcourse I know about pyinstaller. But my windows defender keeps deleting my .exe file after compiling. And since I am debugging my script I don't want to whitelist it everytime. Therefore I try to find a solution so that Windows Defender won't delete my .exe file everytime